# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8, 1, 46) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to make a chat bot using tensorflow but getting an value error for shape. I dont know how to resolve it. The error which i am getting is ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8, 1, 46) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
I have also checked the shape of "training variable" it is 26,1,46.

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
import numpy as np
from numpy.__config__ import show
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_batch_ops import batch
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import json
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

from tflearn.layers.core import activation

stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

with open("./intents.json") as file:
    data=json.load(file)
    
#print(data["intents"])

words=[]
labels=[]
docs_x=[]
docs_y =[]
for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        #picking up key/main words from pattern using nltk
        wrds=nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])
        
        if(intent["tag"] not in labels):
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w !="?"]
#finding distinct words so using set
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

labels = sorted(labels)

#one hot encoding the words
training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

for x,doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag=[]
    
    wrds=[stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]
    
    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)
    
    output_row = out_empty[:]
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1
    
    training.append([bag])
    output.append(output_row)

training = np.array(training)
output = np.array(output)
print("shape",training.shape)

ops.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
#8neuron for hidden layer
net=tflearn.fully_connected(net,8)
net=tflearn.fully_connected(net,8)
net=tflearn.fully_connected(net,len(output[0]),activation="softmax")
net=tflearn.regression(net)

model=tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000,batch_size=8,show_metric=True)
model.save("model.tflearn")
```

Thank you

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jgq8QvpNmkahrr0mbH8Gg7RLdDFLs8G/view?usp=sharing
The link to json data file